# Minimal Installation

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, uefi, ubuntu-minimal, ubuntu-wiki

I'm trying to do a minimal installation of Ubuntu for my HTPC. I want a minimal Ubuntu + X + Kodi.

Minimal Ubuntu is proving to be a problem.

- [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) is not suitable because UEFI is not supported (I don't want to install in BIOS mode).
- [LowMemorySystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) also appears out-dated. I couldn't find command-line install in the 18.04 installers.
- The only [alternate CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/AlternateInstall) is Lubuntu and even that does not provide any custom installation options. The default install is about 3.5GB.

Any suggestions to do a small, minimal base installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: The minimal-install desktop option installed everything, then ran a script that just removed a predefined set of packages. Lubuntu didn't to my knowledge offer that option and isn't what you're after anyway. You can just install & then remove the packages yourself as it's pretty easy.  You mention the command-line option (available with server installs) which is a choice (*yeah the wiki [help.ubuntu.com] page is rather old, I'll look at it later if I can*)

Comment: The wiki page update makes more sense when Ubuntu 14.04 LTS reaches EOL as it contains information that is still possible with older releases of Ubuntu. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)

Comment: The challenge is to know which packages to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use Ubuntu Server ( https://www.ubuntu.com/#download ). Ubuntu Server does have UEFI support. During the installation you will be asked to install server packages, just don't install any if you don't want to. After installation you will have a minimal Ubuntu with a commandline interface. Now you are able to install the packages needed to build the system you want.

Kind regards, Jeroen.

Comment: +1. I have used this method in order to install a small custom system in UEFI mode, so I can confirm that it works.

Comment: I had tried the live server ISO and it did not provide any customization options. I just tried the alternate _ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso_ and it does provide some options. With only openssh server selected, the installation was 2.2GB. 
Is there any fundamental difference between server & desktop editions? e.g. kernel tuning, etc.

Comment: Hi Rubpa, there are no fundamental differences between the desktop and the server editions, the same kernel is being used. (Not taking into account xserver, DE and graphical packages).

Comment: Thanks jeroen! Ubuntu server (not live-server) + plymouth-theme + xorg + lightdm + lightdm-gtk-greeter + openbox seems to give me the minimal system that I want.

Comment: Nice, you're welcome!